# Entity Framework Code First relationship save Issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Having some troubles with saving new Employee to database.

Project Model(useless fiels removed):

```
public class Project{
        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeManager.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

EmployeeManager.Employee Model:

```
public class Employee{
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ProjectsManager.Project ProjectObj { get; set; }
    }
```

Function:

```
public async Task AddNewEmployeeAsync(string projectId, string email, string fullname){       
        var projectInfo = await GetByIdAsync(projectId);
        var userInfo = new ApplicationUser();

        if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(_ => _.Email == email)){
            userInfo = await _context.Users.FirstAsync(_ => _.Email == email);
        }
        else{
            ....
            userInfo = user;
        }

        projectInfo.Employees.Add(new EmployeeManager.Employee{
            User = userInfo
        });

        _context.Entry(projectInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And after all that, i have no changes in database.

Why?

If i use _context.Employees.Add() -> it creates new project entity in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Entity Framework to create the correct relationships (one to many) without configuration (FluentApi) you need to make a couple of changes to Employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; } //foreign key maybe a string as defined in your Project class
    public virtual ProjectsManager.Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And how to add new Employee in that case? (sorry for stupid question)

Comment: You can add a new employee as per your question. Just add one to your Employees collection of project